# PDOException error when running SQL Query in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to run this SQL Query using PHP PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("select * from billing_pdf_archive where invoice_number = :invoice_number and sequence = :sequence ");

$stmt->execute(array(
                     ':invoicenumber' => $_GET["inv"], 
                     ':sequence' => $_GET["seq"]
                    )
);

$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

Note: `$_GET["inv"]` and `$_GET["seq"]` show data when echoed

but i am getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in /home/integra/public_html/lifeline/billing/resendpdfinvoice.php:94 Stack trace: #0 /home/integra/public_html/lifeline/billing/resendpdfinvoice.php(94): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/integra/public_html/lifeline/billing/resendpdfinvoice.php on line 94

i cannot work out what is wrong with it

Comment: `invoicenumber` vs `invoice_number`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
where invoice_number = :invoice_number
                               ^---- underscore here

$stmt->execute(array(':invoicenumber' => $_GET["inv"], 
                              ^---no underscore here
```

Answer (score 2):

See here

```
invoicenumber!=invoice_number
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your query contains `:invoice_number` when your execution statement asks for `:invoicenumber`. Try setting them to the same value (`:invoice_number` for example)

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("select * from billing_pdf_archive"
    . " where invoice_number = :invoice_number and sequence = :sequence ");

$stmt->execute(array(
    ':invoice_number' => $_GET["inv"], 
    ':sequence' => $_GET["seq"]
));
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```